# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation

When I try to execute automation script I'm getting error as "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream`"

I've added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

in the pom.xml file. But still I'm facing the error.

Attached my testutil and pom.xml file for reference. Attached image highlighted line im facing the issue.[testutil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwHsn.jpg)

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>automationAutomationTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>automationTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>automationTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   
  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

  <dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
    <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0-beta</version>
          </dependency>
          
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.html) of UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream:
Since:2.7

So change 2.6 to 2.7 .

Comment: I'm using 2.11 :(

Comment: can confirm that upgrading the mentioned commons-io dependency usually works